# <ion-spinner> somente funciona uma vez, como corrgir isso?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic, load

Cenário:

A diretiva `<ion-spinner>` é usado na tela A, mas quando é usado na tela seguinte, tela B, ocorre um problema, em que ela aparece, mas não tem a animação.

Alguém já passou por esse problema, e conseguiu corrigir?

Answer (score 1):

Já tive problemas com spinner quando estava utilizando versão antiga do Ionic.
De uma olhada no arquivo ionic/version.json e veja qual versão está usando.
Verifique no site http://code.ionicframework.com/# se você está mesmo com uma versão atual.

Comment: Obrigado @AndréVicente, mas estou usando a versão 1.2.4 (Copenhagen). :/

Answer (score -1):

```
//We need to let the ion-infinite-scroll know that we’re done loading in the new items. 
//To do this, we need to broadcast the scroll.infiniteScrollComplete event.
$scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
```

é só adicionar essa linha quando sua função retornar os valores da lista. 
exemplo:

```
var successCallback = function(data){
  $scope.list = $scope.list.concat(data);
  $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
});
```